# How to do a button with a background image and bottom text on a black background

Tags: android, button

I want to a do button with a background image.
Furthemore, at the bottom of the button I want to put a text on black background.

Example:

[image]

Is it possible to do that? If so, how?

Comment: first learn the rules of this community: #1 we don't do homeworks, #2 you should show some effort and show a SSCCE of what you are trying to accomplish..

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. And by using a single TextView without any other controls.
Note that you can use a TextView as if it was a Button.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f000"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/your_picture"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:text="TEXT"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `RelativeLayout` (or another `ViewGroup`) and into it insert an `ImageView`, as well as a `TextView`. Set the background of the `RelativeLayout` to a black color. Set the text color of the `TextView` to white. Then, set a `View.OnClickListener` for the whole `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I am trying to do it but i can't.Could you write example code??

Comment: This is as much as I can provide without seeing your progress. Please edit your original post with what you have tried so far. Also, try Tobor's answer - it's more efficient.