# How match the TextView to Layout in my example?

Tags: android, button, layout

I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/tlo10"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

               <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                       >

                   <TextView
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:background="#f000"
                           android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                           android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                           android:padding="4dp"
                           android:gravity="center"
                           android:textSize="16sp"
                           android:textStyle="bold"
                           android:textColor="#ffff"
                           android:text="Button1"
                           />


               </RelativeLayout>

              <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"

                      >
                  <TextView
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:background="#f000"
                          android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                          android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                          android:padding="4dp"
                          android:gravity="center"
                          android:textSize="16sp"
                          android:textStyle="bold"
                          android:textColor="#ffff"
                          android:text="Button2"
                          />

              </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="15dip"
            >

                  <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                      <TextView
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:background="#f000"
                              android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                              android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                              android:padding="4dp"
                              android:gravity="center"
                              android:textSize="16sp"
                              android:textStyle="bold"
                              android:textColor="#ffff"
                              android:text="Button3"
                              />
                  </RelativeLayout>

                 <RelativeLayout
                         android:layout_width="0dip"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:layout_weight="1" >

                     <TextView
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:background="#f000"
                             android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                             android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                             android:padding="4dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:textSize="16sp"
                             android:textStyle="bold"
                             android:textColor="#ffff"
                             android:text="Button4"
                             />

                 </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As result I  received this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6jnhwqo4jd5ftp/menu2a.jpg 
So this is OK.
But when I added one more row of layout a  received this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwa9ai8aq8g3ype/menu2b.jpg

Text no display. How match the TextView to Layout in my example ??

Comment: Why are you putting the textviews inside RelativeLayout???

Comment: I am writing with regard this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608966/how-do-button-with-background-image-and-bottom-text-on-black-background

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

Put your linear layout inside scrollview.. and for better performance remove the relativelayout surrounding text views and copy the weights inside the textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >



               <TextView
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:background="#f000"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                       android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                       android:padding="4dp"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:textSize="16sp"
                       android:textStyle="bold"
                       android:textColor="#ffff"
                       android:text="Button1"
                       />





              <TextView
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:background="#f000"
                      android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                      android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                      android:padding="4dp"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textColor="#ffff"
                      android:text="Button2"
                      />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >



               <TextView
                       android:layout_width="0dp"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:background="#f000"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                       android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                       android:padding="4dp"
                       android:gravity="center"
                       android:textSize="16sp"
                       android:textStyle="bold"
                       android:textColor="#ffff"
                       android:text="Button1"
                       />





              <TextView
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:background="#f000"
                      android:drawableTop="@drawable/zdj_transport"
                      android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                      android:padding="4dp"
                      android:gravity="center"
                      android:textSize="16sp"
                      android:textStyle="bold"
                      android:textColor="#ffff"
                      android:text="Button2"
                      />

        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```